# Firefox addon for black background?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the white background in webpages to another color.](https://superuser.com/questions/181214/change-the-white-background-in-webpages-to-another-color)

Is there a Firefox addon which makes every site's background black and text white?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firefox, go to `Tools > Options > Content` and click on `Colours` button.

Select black for the "Background", white for the "Text", and clear the checkboxes near "Allow pages to choose their own colours, instead of my selections above" and "Use system colours".

[image]

Comment: seems to me that this is the only solution, thanks

Comment: but then you loose a lot of styling by the website , stuff starts looking pretty awful

Comment: you could try fiddling with greasemonkey ,