# How do I get Firefox to show a default black screen when a page is loading?

Tags: firefox, colors

I've installed some useful Firefox addons, like "stylish", which make pages darker so my monitor isn't so blinding at night. The problem is that Firefox turns blinding white as the page is loading. It only shows the pages' style or the addons' style when the page is loaded, which can be a while sometimes. How do I get the default background color to be black?

I already tried setting the "Background Color" under "Content" -> "Colors" (as shown below). It either doesn't do anything, or it makes all text on all pages completely unreadable if I choose "Always" in the dropdown. Is there another way?

[image: This doesn't work]

Comment: Is this happening on every page load - eg. when clicking links and typing new url in address bar - or only when going from empty (blank) tab?

Comment: Just tried it. It doesn't seem to happen when clicking a link, only when typing a new url into the menu bar and pressing enter. Between pressing enter and the page beginning to load some of its css the default is white.

Comment: In that case manually overriding css for blank tab might help you. The file which applies additional css to firefox is in it's profile folder (google location for your OS) and following subpath: `chrome/userContent.css`. Try setting `background-color` property for `#newtab-vertical-margin`.

Comment: i guess it goes without saying - but these changes will be applied only after firefox process restart. This css file is loaded at all times, that's why i'm hoping it'll help once you find the correct element to configure.

Comment: I can't seem to find this file. Is it in the root of the profile directory?

Comment: On windows it should be in `Profiles/<random-string>.default/chrome/`. On linux in `~/.mozilla/firefox/<random-string>.default/chrome/`.

Comment: There's no `chrome` directory there. Although there is a `storage/permanent/chrome`. I'm running Firefox Developer Edition 48.0a2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43267/discussion-between-marek-rost-and-hassan).

Comment: create it then - both the folder and file. also come to chat.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/603218/how-to-make-the-aboutblank-page-black-or-any-other-color-in-firefox

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer from http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=2989626#p2989626 with help from http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css.

The `Mozilla` directory depends on your operating system:

> Windows NT (NT4.x/2000/XP/Vista/7/8/10): `"%APPDATA%\Mozilla\"`
>
> Windows 95 (without Desktop Update): `C:\Windows\Mozilla`
>
> Windows 95 (with Desktop Update)/98/Me: `C:\Windows\Application Data\Mozilla\`, `C:\Windows\Profiles\[Windows login/user name]\Application Data\Mozilla\`
>
> Unix/Linux: `~/.mozilla/`
>
> Mac OS X: `~/Library/Mozilla/`, `~/Library/Application Support/`

After finding the `Mozilla` directory you have to go through a few more directories to find your profile directory.  See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox.

In your profile directory, if it doesn't exist, create the `chrome` directory.  Then create a new text file in `chrome` called `userChrome.css` with the following contents:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
browser { background-color: #333 !important; }
```

You can change the background color to whatever you want.  Unfortunately for me the screen still flashes white very briefly but this fix is still very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using [ShadowFox](https://github.com/overdodactyl/ShadowFox)! Thanks guys for your hard work!

First find how which is your default profile in `about:profiles`. Find the entry for `Default Profile`.

Then enable the user profile customization in `about:config`

```
toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets;true
```

And finally install ShadowFox. For mac users:

```sh
brew install srkomodo/tap/shadowfox-updater
shadowfox
# follow instructions, pick default profile
```