# Change Firefox new tab background

Tags: firefox, colors, firefox-extensions, themes, firefox-57

I always use dark personas theme or the default compact dark theme that comes included with Firefox and I don't like the default background color being white when I open a new tab.
There was an add on I used that let me customize new tabs but it's gone now with Firefox 57...

So, how can I do to change new tabs background?

Comment: Dark theme for Firefox https://overdodactyl.github.io/ShadowFox/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think this may interest others as well.

**ANSWER UPDATE (as of 2020)**

By now there's a lot of cool and interesting addons that do the job in great way, let me mention some of my favorite in a brief list:

1. [Firefox Color](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-color/)
   This imho is really THE DEFINITIVE ONE and A MUST HAVE! Not only it lets you deeply customize almost everything of Firefox GUI the way you like it (including new tabs background of course), it also lets you share the theme you made if you want. If this isn't enough, let me add this addon is develope by Mozilla itself.
2. [Tabliss](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabliss/)
   This is a really nice one (I personally use and love it). It lets you customize the new tabs background not only choosing for a color but also beautiful background images and add widgets (like showing the time for instance). (As a last note here let me say Tabliss is like joining the features of [New Tab Override](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/), [New Tab Wallpaper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/newtab-wallpaper/), [Beauty Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/beauty-tab/), [New Tab Splash](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/splash-new-tab/) and [Clock New Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clock-new-tab-dashboard/) addons all togheter.)
3. There are also some addons that, despite background, lets you customize tiles on new tabs as well, I think you may like it and find the thing useful so I'll provide some worth a try imho:
   [Infinity New Tab (Pro)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/infinity-new-tab-pro-firefox/),
   [nightTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nighttab/),
   [New Tab Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-tools/).

That said, if you're looking for something minimalistic there are also addons that work straight forward and provide just the very basic feature to only change the new tabs background to something dark, for example [Dark New Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blank-new-tab-page)
or even [Black New Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/black-new-tab/) ...also, if you want, you can still juggle with CSS (see point 3 of original answer below).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

So far I know a couple of addons to achieve that and a way to do without addons (as it seems a lot of them are disappearing day by day), here we go then:

1. [Customize about:newtab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customize-about-newtab/) (please see point 3 below)

This is a specific add on for the task, it not only let's you change the background color but also choose a background image and also resize and align it as you like... nice!

2. [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) (please see point 3 below)

Stylish is an add on with a broader spectrum of functionality; it lets you customize Firefox itself as long as manage/install themes and skins for lots of popular websites such as Google, Facebook, YouTube and many others... I think it's overkill if you only need it for the task we are dealing with here.

3. **Neither of the above will work with Firefox 57 due to added restrictions**. Stylus with Firefox 57's new tab page shows this message:

> As a security precaution, the browser prohibits extensions from
> affecting its built-in pages (like chrome://version, the standard new
> tab page as of Chrome 61, about:addons, and so on) as well as other
> extensions' pages. Each browser also restricts access to its own
> extensions gallery (like Chrome Web Store or AMO).

So, let's leave addons aside and get our hands dirty!

You may decide you don't want to use an addon for this, well in this case here's what to do:

- write `about:profiles` in the Firefox address bar and select <kbd>Open Folder</kbd> in correspondence of the "Root Directory" of the user profile you want to customize (usually there's only one);
- by now the profile's root folder should have opened, create (if it is not present yet) a new folder named `chrome`;
- create (if it is not present already) a new file named `userContent.css`
  inside the `chrome` folder and put the following code in it:

  ```css
        @-moz-document url("about:newtab") {  
            body {
                background-color: #000000 !important;
            }
        }
  ```

If you can juggle with CSS, you may also add some code to set a background image if you like (I suggest to eventually put the images in the same folder with the CSS).

***You may need to restart Firefox to make customization being applied.***

*Credits for this last point goes to [DIENER_](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/693t7t/how_to_change_newtab_backgrounds_color/)*

Comment: For doing the same thing with Firefox `about:blank` page you can refer to this other Q&A: https://superuser.com/questions/603218/how-to-make-the-aboutblank-page-black-or-any-other-color-in-firefox

Comment: Bonus points(if I could) for the Firefox 57+ compatible method.

Comment: Update-comment: Make sure you don't miss this new and awesome Firefox extension: [Tabliss](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabliss/?src=external-tabliss.io) works great! (Available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabliss-your-new-tab/hipekcciheckooncpjeljhnekcoolahp) as well)

Comment: Another good WebExtension for FF to achieve the purpose here: [New Tab Override](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/)

Comment: Thanks! just made this to match breeze dark plasma 5 theme colors https://gitlab.com/snippets/1781039

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox 67

Comment: @VladimirJovanović I updated the answer, check it out :)

Comment: As a side note about "CSS juggling" to put a wallpaper image you can simply add a line: `background-image: url(...) !important;` ( also have a look at [this other Q/A here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1495946/how-do-i-change-the-background-image-of-home-page-in-firefox) )

Answer (score 16):

Open `about:config` and change the value `browser.display.background_color` to the color of your choice. I'm using #595959 (neutral gray).

This  works with blank tab or "Firefox Home".

Sadly, opening tab quickly or when the browser is on heavy load will still result of a white flash.

If you don't know how to use about:config please read https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox 67

Comment: This does work for me on Firefox 67.0.4 (64-bit) on Arch Linux. However, the solution is not ideal due to the white flash, as described in the answer.

Comment: Works in Firefox 71

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox 76.0.1 on Manjaro.

Comment: Works with Firefox 81 on Windows. By far the simplest answer.

Comment: You can change firefox home background color under `Preferences (not advanced) > General > Fonts and Colors > Color > Background Color` NOTE this will work if your new tab default is "blank page"

Comment: this solution also changes background for certain webpages - for example https://drewdevault.com/
so it is sub-optimal

Answer (score 2):

Well, I must say the solution given by @danicotra does work for new tab, even with Firefox 57. However, during loading of a page, a blank flash will still systematically burn your eyes.

Here is an other proposal of content for your `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/chrome/userContent.css`, which does darken a few more places, but won't resolve the blank flash on load.

```
/* https://userstyles.org/styles/90565/firefox-adjust-white-flash-when-opening-new-tab */
/* https://userstyles.org/styles/142191/remove-new-tab-flash */
@-moz-document url-prefix(about:preferences), url-prefix(about:blank), url-prefix(about:newtab) {
  html, body, #newtab-customize-overlay {
    background: #303030 !important;
    color: #b2b2b2 !important;
  } 
}

@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xul)
{

  browser[type="content-primary"]
  {
    background: #303030 !important;
    color: #b2b2b2 !important;
  }
}

@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xul)
{

  browser[type="content-primary"], tabbrowser tabpanels, #appcontent > #content
  {
    background: #1B1B1B url("chrome://global/skin/media/imagedoc-darknoise.png") repeat fixed !important;
    color: #b2b2b2 !important;
  }
}

@-moz-document url(about:blank),
               url(about:preferences),
               url(about:config),
               url(about:newtab)
{
  #newtab-window,
  html,
  body, 
  #newtab-customize-overlay 
  {
    background: #1B1B1B url("chrome://global/skin/media/imagedoc-darknoise.png") repeat fixed;
    color: #b2b2b2 !important;
  }
}

html>body {
  background: #303030 !important;
  color: #b2b2b2 !important;
}
```

Comment: An almost working solution for blank flash https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/6s2l0w/removing_the_white_flash_before_a_page_loads/ but some white elements might still flash while loading page.

Answer (score 1):

OK, based on the answers from psychoslave and danicotra, I figured out a solution that works for me (my goal was to have a background image on the new tab page which I have set to `about:blank`). psychoslave's solution changes basically every Firefox's page which I don't want to but thanks to the beginning of his code I was able to figure out there are the `url-prefix` parts which make the whole thing apparently possible.

Note: For just a background color on new tab, open `about:config`, search for `browser.display.background_color` update its value with hex color code and you can drop this altogether.

1. Find your profile root folder in `about:profiles`.
2. Create a folder named `chrome` in your profile root.
3. Create `userContent.css` with this content:

   ```
   /* https://userstyles.org/styles/90565/firefox-adjust-white-flash-when-opening-new-tab */
   /* https://userstyles.org/styles/142191/remove-new-tab-flash */
   @-moz-document url-prefix(about:blank), url-prefix(about:newtab) {
     html, body, #newtab-customize-overlay {
       background: url("konachan-steins-gate-s.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed !important; 
       background-size: cover !important;
     } 
   }
   ```
4. Copy the image right next to the `userContent.css` file (FF didn't take any absolute paths elsewhere for me).
5. In `about:config`, set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` so FF actually allows this customization.
6. Restart your Firefox for the changes to take effect.

I confirm this works on Windows 10, Ubuntu and Xubuntu; Firefox 72.0.2, 73.0.

A big thanks to the other contributors mentioned above and to [this thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/brmi8v/psa_firefox_v69_users_will_have_to_set_a_pref_to/).

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, add the following file (or append to it, if it exists):

`~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme = true
```

(you might also find and toggle this option through your Linux distro settings manager)

Similar question https://superuser.com/a/1546544/1169541

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firefox Color extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-color/). Unfortunately,  as of writing this post (firefox color version 2.1.7) does not change the color of "blank tabs".

Instead, choose default tab behavior to be "Firefox Home (Default)" and turn off all the Firefox Home Content. It will behave essentially as a "blank tab" that now responds to theme changes.

Answer (score -2):

I like psychoslave's option but if u do not want to change the google background or those sites background what use the browser default background change the last three line like this:

```
#root{   background: #303030 !important;   color: #b2b2b2 !important; }
```

And here is the full code, copyed from psychoslave's answer.

```
>     /* https://userstyles.org/styles/90565/firefox-adjust-white-flash-when-opening-new-tab
> */ /* https://userstyles.org/styles/142191/remove-new-tab-flash */ @-moz-document url-prefix(about:preferences), url-prefix(about:blank),
> url-prefix(about:newtab) {   html, body, #newtab-customize-overlay {
>     background: #303030 !important;
>     color: #b2b2b2 !important;   }  }
> 
> @-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xul) {
> 
>   browser[type="content-primary"]   {
>     background: #303030 !important;
>     color: #b2b2b2 !important;   } }
> 
> @-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xul) {
> 
>   browser[type="content-primary"], tabbrowser tabpanels, #appcontent >
> #content   {
>     background: #1B1B1B url("chrome://global/skin/media/imagedoc-darknoise.png") repeat fixed
> !important;
>     color: #b2b2b2 !important;   } }
> 
> @-moz-document url(about:blank),
>                url(about:preferences),
>                url(about:config),
>                url(about:newtab) {   #newtab-window,   html,   body,    #newtab-customize-overlay    {
>     background: #1B1B1B url("chrome://global/skin/media/imagedoc-darknoise.png") repeat fixed;
>     color: #b2b2b2 !important;   } }
> 
> #root {   background: #303030 !important;   color: #b2b2b2 !important; }
```