# How do I change the background image of Home page in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, themes

I want to change the look and feel of the boring home page of Firefox browser by changing the background image to something I want.

Basic system details:

- OS: GNU/Linux
- Firefox Version: 72.0a1 (2019-10-22) (64-bit)

It would be better for me if I can do that without ad-ons...

Comment: The reason I asked this question and answered my question is just because I was looking for the answer for many months. But today I asked the Mozilla community, where I got a solution https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1271362

And I am sharing so that others can get the answer easily from here. Please mark as duplicate if this is one.

I am happy to delete the question and answer altogether this if it's not helpful at all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Firefox, there's no way to change the background image of the home page (new tab) from the Settings. Add-ons can surely do that, but there's a better approach: We can create a CSS file and tell Firefox to load that file when it starts.

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Go to `about:support` in the address bar. View the section **"Application Basics"** ➔ **Profile Directory** (or **"Profile Folder"** on MacOS) ➔ click the button **"Open Directory"** (or **"Show in Finder"** on MacOS):
   [image: Firefox about:support screenshot options]

It should open your Firefox profile directory, which is usually in your $HOME directory.

2. Create a directory called **chrome** inside the opened directory, if it's not already there.
3. Go to the **chrome** directory and (a) create a directory called **img** and (b) create a file called **userContent.css**. Move your image to the *img* directory.
4. Open `userContent.css` in any text editor and paste the following code:

```css
@-moz-document url(about:home), url(about:newtab), url(about:privatebrowsing) {
    .click-target-container *, .top-sites-list * {
        color: #fff !important ;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #222 !important ;
    }

    body::before {
        content: "" ;
        z-index: -1 ;
        position: fixed ;
        top: 0 ;
        left: 0 ;
        background: #f9a no-repeat url(img/cherry-blossom-1260646.jpg) center ;
        background-size: cover ;
        width: 100vw ;
        height: 100vh ;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change the file name in `url(img/cherry-blossom-1260646.jpg)` to your preferred image.

Save the file and quit the editor.

5. Go to the url `about:config`, accept the risk (we will not really do anything harmful here, nothing to worry about), and in the Search Bar, paste `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`, and set the value to true. This tells Firefox to load the CSS file at startup.
6. Restart Firefox if it's running.

---

**Explanation to the CSS code**

**A**

```css
@-moz-document url(about:home), url(about:newtab), url(about:privatebrowsing)
```

Enables the background on Home Tabs, New Tabs, and in Private Browsing tabs.

**B**

```css
.click-target-container *, .top-sites-list * {
    color: #fff !important ;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #222 !important ;
}
```

Changes the "Top Sites" and "Highlights" colours to white with a dark text-shadow. For lighter wallpaper, you need to edit the colours to make it look more comfortable to you.

**C**

```css
body::before {
    content: "" ;
    z-index: -1 ;
    position: fixed ;
    top: 0 ;
    left: 0 ;
    background: #f9a no-repeat url(img/cherry-blossom-1260646.jpg) center ;
    background-size: cover ;
    width: 100vw ;
    height: 100vh ;
}
```

loads the image (here, *img/cherry-blossom-1260646.jpg*) to `body::before` which has a fixed position and the width and height of the viewport. If the background image is loading or not found, the background colour is set to *#f9a*.

The `background-size: cover` makes it auto adjustable with Firefox and zoom in/out doesn't affect the image size.

On GNU/Linux and Unix systems, you can load images from the `/usr/share/backgrounds/` as well.

---

**After a restart Firefox should look something like this:**

[image: Firefox Home Tab screenshot, with custom background image]

Comment: Thanks you very much!
Do you know why Firefox refuses to use a wallpaper from `~/Pictures` and works only with wallpapers from `/usr/share/backgrounds`?

Comment: Hi,thanks for let me knowing that. I am not exactly sure about why it doesn't work from other path rather than `/usr/share/backgrounds` or the `chrome` directory itself. I have updated the answer so that it will work on any system...

Comment: Hey, does this works in the latest firefox ?   I'm struggling to make it work. Also, my userChrome is enabled correctly.

Comment: Yes this worked for every single version released after I wrote the answer. Make sure you are opening the proper URL. Also, you can try putting the image in the same directory as the image.

Comment: Confirmed to work in Firefox 88.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: might refer to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1336566

Comment: Tried this a couple months back, but didn't see any change. Today, while looking closely at the about:support screen, I noticed the "Try clearing the startup cache" option at top right. I did that, and it worked! Not sure if this is a new option.

Comment: Why not just use `background-image` instead of all this rigamarole in the CSS? and `background-color` as a fallback