# change firefox newtab background

Tags: firefox, javascript

I am trying to change the background image of the Firefox New Tab. I have been doing the solutions given, but I want to make it dynamic. Is there anyway that a JavaScript file can be used like `userContent.css`?

Comment: Have you tried extensions such as Tabliss? https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tabliss/?src=search

Comment: You can use this extention as well:https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-style-script/

Comment: Yes you can, using userContent.css, see here: https://superuser.com/questions/1495946/how-do-i-change-the-background-image-of-home-page-in-firefox