# Can we really change the browser screen background in black and the text in white in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, colors

I wish to have a black background for my browser screen especially in Chrome without any bugs.

Comment: The background is set by the webpage, not by the browser. You could use an extension that hooks into the code of the websites (like adblockers do), but that would probably break a lot of websites. Here's how to do it in firefox: http://superuser.com/questions/181214/change-the-white-background-in-webpages-to-another-color?rq=1

Comment: Dude I asked for Chrome..!! @Peter

Comment: That would be why this was a comment, not an answer. Also, if you read your question, you asked for any browser and "especially for chrome".

Comment: OK.!! now i  got it

Answer (score 1):

Earlier, I had found a extension 'Color Change for Google' which worked only for the Google search page. Then, I found the following answer on [this Google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BnLnYe3SK8k):

> Visit this site
>
> https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/color.html
>
> then drag 'invert lightness' to the bookmark bar for easy access. This is a quick and easy way to flip most pages, framed or unframed, without too much hassle. The result is usually more legible.

I tried it myself and it works well within your conditions (Of course it would work only on white web pages, but most are white after all).
Hope it helps!