# I find websites with white text on black background hard to read. What options do I have if they don't let me switch?

Tags: browser, colors

Some webmasters make their websites have white text on black background.  I find this hard to read for longer than a short period of time.  I get various visual anomalies and my eyes get watery.

[Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/) has a cookie based preference to allow you to switch themes from white on black (default) to black text on white background.  This is great.  Not all websites do this.

How can I manage a website/webapp that does not explicitly have this same function baked in?  Usually I am reading news, articles, how-to's, and that sort of thing, so they are lengthy, detailed, and require time to read.

I imagine that I could modify the HTML or the CSS, potentially with GreaseMonkey.  I found a Firefox extension a while ago called  [Blank Your Monitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blank-your-monitor-easy-readin/) that will change the text and background.  However, it changes all of the open tabs to those new colors.  Not just the current or selected tab(s).

Instead of looking for a technological work around, should I contact the webmaster?

As I delve into EE, Linux, FOSS, and modern maker based sites, I encounter this phenomenon more often.  Apparently the taste for white on black is strong with this crowd.

Comment: This isn't a UX question, but more something that may be asked on Super User, so I'll try to migrate it.

Comment: Related: [Change the white background in webpages to another color](http://superuser.com/q/181214). This changes in the opposite direction to what you want, but you can edit the scripts (there are several choices) to give you black text on a white background.

Comment: Make some CSS for Stylish...

Answer (score 3):

Your options depend on the browser and/or OS you're using.

**Chrome**

Google has its own official [High Contrast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph) extension for Chrome which gets good reviews. It allows you to invert colours by clicking on an icon in its toolbar. It provides a number of options and, in your case, would be ideal because it does allow you to set it on a per-site basis. There's also a keyboard shortcut to toggle inversion on any site you want.

**Firefox**

Firefox has a couple of options, namely:

- [Blank your monitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blank-your-monitor-easy-readin/)
- My Flavours

**MacOS X**

Now, if you happen to be using an Apple Mac, you also have the option of inverting the whole screen as part of the Accessibility options in System Preferences (in some versions of Mac OS X it's under Universal Access).

**MacOS X / Windows / Linux**

You can also use f.lux

**Feedback**

Oh, and in reference to your last question, yes I'd send feedback. Even if it is a 'complaint', feedback is always a gift. It's up to the recipient what, if anything they do with it, but at least there's a chance they'll do something.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't post two links once the question was moved here. But here they are: [f.lux] https://justgetflux.com/ and [My Flavolours] http://userstyles.org/styles/2187/myfavolours-global-custom-color-scheme

Comment: f.lux doesn't swap text and background colours in browsers.

Comment: Point taken - I should have been a little clearer as to why I listed it last under the operating system labels. f.lux may, however, be helpful for the OP in a range of situations, especially if he's experiencing visual anomalies and watery eyes.

Comment: In addition he already said "Blank your Monitor" doesn't work for him. You should read the question more carefully.